# Blazor text input call method each time when new character is changed without pressing enter

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, mudblazor

I am building a Blazor Maui app using Mudblazor and I would like to perform a search each time when the input is changed. I have the following:

```
<MudTextField T="string" @bind-Value="@Search" Label="Standard" Variant="Variant.Text"></MudTextField>

@code{
 public string Search
        {
            get
            {
                return _search;
            }
            set
            {
                _search = value;
                try
                {
                    var t = Task.Run(() => PerformSearch());
                    t.Wait();
                    StateHasChanged();
                }
                catch { }
            }
        }
}
```

This works if I type and press enter, I would like without the pressing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [MudBlazor docs](https://mudblazor.com/components/textfield#immediate-vs-debounced) you can achieve your desired behavior by setting some attributes on the component and handling the `OnDebounceIntervalElapsed` event (you can play with the `DebounceInterval` to get the behavior you'd like):

```
<MudTextField T="string" 
              @bind-Value="@Search" 
              Label="Standard" 
              Variant="Variant.Text"
              Immediate="true"
              DebounceInterval="100"
              OnDebounceIntervalElapsed="DoSearch">
</MudTextField>

@code {
    public string Search { get; set; }

    private async Task DoSearch(string text)
    {
        // use the text parameter as needed here
        await Task.Run(() => PerformSearch());
    }
}
```